# Initiating a form to change MySQL data by a HTML link?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Curiosity killed the cat...

Here's a good one that I need some help with, long story short I am trying to update information on MySQL databases, I understand how to do this with a form on the website and a bit of PHP coding. However, what I am trying to do is create a link on my webpage, just a standard html link, which - once clicked will do the same thing as a form almost (without all the information) which would change a piece of info in the database. Example:

Click "here" to change set number from 0 to 1

Once the user clicks "here" the number in the database changes from 0 to 1.

Comment: Haven't written this code yet.

Comment: So you don't want to send any information to the server, only do a specific action when that link is clicked?

Comment: No new information, in the database i am using an enum type field for this with default at 0, so the link would change that number to 1?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Ajax. Even though you need to use another PHP file, that won't refresh the HTML page.

1) The link should be something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeValue(1)">Click here to set number from 0 to 1</a>
```

2) The Javascript/JQuery code:

```
function changeValue(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'changeIt.php?value='+value,
        success : function() {
           //does nothing
        }
    });

}
```

3) And finally, the code in `changeIt.php` file should be something like:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
//Use MySQL to change the value in the Database
```

Comment: I think page should remain the same

Comment: I changed the answer to fit that requirement